# Order list elements according to a vector

Tags: r, list, sorting, variables

Say I have a list like:

```
my_list <- list(name1 = 'a', name2 = 'b', name3 = 'c', name4 = 'd')
```

And I want to order it according to the following variable:

```
my_var=c('name2','name1','name4','name3')
```

I tried the following, but does not work as I expect:

```
my_list[order(match(my_list, my_var))]
my_list[match(my_list, my_var)]
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: `my_list[my_var]`? Are you actually talking about ordering, i.e. sorting values which may contain duplicate elements? It looks like you're subsetting by name.

Comment: ok it is indeed `my_list[my_var]`, not sure why I was thinking I had to use `match()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want to use `match` like this

```
> my_list[match(my_var, names(my_list))]
$name2
[1] "b"

$name1
[1] "a"

$name4
[1] "d"

$name3
[1] "c"
```

***BUT***, you already can simply run `my_list[my_var]` to achieve what you want.

Comment: yes, this is it, I had a short circuit, I don't work much with lists

Comment: The advantage of `match` is that it can address missings if `nomatch=0` is used. However I think _my_var_ should come first. Compare: `my_list[match(c('name2', 'name999', 'name1','name4','name3'), names(my_list), nomatch=0)]`, `my_list[match(names(my_list), c('name2', 'name999', 'name1','name4','name3'), nomatch=0)]`.

Comment: @jay.sf yes, thanks for the comment, and that's a really appealing benefit of using `match`