# Why does R colnames ignore the vector with specified names and only pay attention to the index?

Tags: r, dataframe, rename, rbind, r-colnames

I came across some weird behavior in R. Imagine that I have this data frame, and I want to change the names of the columns by using colnames and a vector:

```
df <- data.frame(a = seq(1,10), b = seq(11,20), c = seq(31,40))
colnames(df) <- c(`b` = 'B1', `a` = 'A2', `c` = 'C3')
```

This gives the following df:

```
  B1 A2 C3
1   1 11 31
2   2 12 32
3   3 13 33
4   4 14 34
5   5 15 35
6   6 16 36
7   7 17 37
8   8 18 38
9   9 19 39
10 10 20 40
```

Notice that the data is still in the same order. So, `a` is actually replaced with 'B1' and `b` is replaced with 'A2'. But, it should look like this if colnames paid attention to the name specification:

```
   A2 B1 C3
1   1 11 31
2   2 12 32
3   3 13 33
4   4 14 34
5   5 15 35
6   6 16 36
7   7 17 37
8   8 18 38
9   9 19 39
10 10 20 40
```

It seems that colnames is completely ignoring the name specification.

I understand the simple solution is to just order the names how you want them saved. However, I want to know if there is a way to specify them in a vector and for that vector to match the old name to the new name. This is just a simple example, what I actually have is more complicated.

What I want to do is ensure that whenever I am renaming column names, they are replaced in the appropriate way so that when I combine dataframes the data under the column name is matched as intended.

Comment: "it should look like this if colnames paid attention to the name specification". Yes, it should. But why do you think `colnames` _would_ pay attention to the names of a named vector? It's not documented anywhere that this is the expected behaviour, and it means that we couldn't use an arbitrarily named vector to name columns. It also means that an unnamed vector wouldn't match any of the existing names, so the behaviour of an unnamed vector would be different from that of a named one. You could just use `rename` from dplyr if you want to specify which columns you are changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match` function in `base` R:

```
df <- data.frame(a = seq(1,10), b = seq(11,20), c = seq(31,40))
new_names <- c(`b` = 'B1', `a` = 'A2', `c` = 'C3')
colnames(df)[match(names(new_names), colnames(df))] <- new_names
```

Comment: Should be `match(names(new_names), colnames(df))`, see my recent [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77844698/order-list-elements-according-to-a-vector/77844745?noredirect=1#comment137235680_77844745) why.

Answer (score 2):

If you replace the values as `newname = oldname` then you can use `rename` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
vec <- c('B1' = "b", 'A2' = "a", 'C3' = "c")

df %>% rename(any_of(vec))

   A2 B1 C3
1   1 11 31
2   2 12 32
3   3 13 33
4   4 14 34
5   5 15 35
6   6 16 36
7   7 17 37
8   8 18 38
9   9 19 39
10 10 20 40
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function that would do this for you using `match()`.

```r
df <- data.frame(a = seq(1,10), b = seq(11,20), c = seq(31,40))

mycolnames <- function(data, newnames, ...){
  oldnames <- colnames(data)
  nn <- newnames[match(oldnames, names(newnames))]
  nn <- ifelse(is.na(nn), oldnames, nn)
  colnames(data) <- nn
  data
}

df <- mycolnames(df, c(`b` = 'B1', `a` = 'A2', `c` = 'C3'))
head(df, n=2)
#>   A2 B1 C3
#> 1  1 11 31
#> 2  2 12 32
```

The benefit of this function is that if you have variables that are not renamed, it will simply use the old names

```r
df <- data.frame(a = seq(1,10), b = seq(11,20), c = seq(31,40))
df <- mycolnames(df, c(`b` = 'B1', `c` = 'C3'))
head(df, n=2)
#>   a B1 C3
#> 1 1 11 31
#> 2 2 12 32
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Should be `match(names(new_names), oldnames)`, see my recent [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77844698/order-list-elements-according-to-a-vector/77844745?noredirect=1#comment137235680_77844745) why.

Answer (score 0):

You could  use `relocate` for that:

```
df |> 
  dplyr::relocate(B1 = b, 
                  A2 = a,
                  C3 = c)
```

or

```
df |> 
  dplyr::relocate(c("B1" = "b", "A2" = "a", "C3" = "c"))
```